# Unrecognized font family 'FontAwesome5Free-Solid'

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

This happened out of nowhere, and I have no idea what happened.

I started to run my app and got this error:

[image]

I believe that it's coming from react-native-vector-icons.

I've tried switching to an older version of react-native-vector-icons, and I still receive the same result.

I've also tried to uninstall react-native-vector-icons, and, when I do, I receive a compiling error.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-
arg/test6/ios/build/test6/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-
normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.o 
/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-
arg/test6/node_modules/react-native-vector-
icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m normal x86_64 
objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I'm pretty stuck at this point.

EDIT:

After I linked react-native-vector-desing and cleared the build folder, I received this error:

```
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-arg/test6/ios/build/test6/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test6.app/AntDesign.ttf':
1) Target 'test6' (project 'test6') has copy command from 
'/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-
arg/test6/node_modules/native-base/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to 
'/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-
arg/test6/ios/build/test6/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/test6.app/AntDesign.ttf'

2) Target 'test6' (project 'test6') has copy command from 
'/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-
arg/test6/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/AntDesign.ttf' to 
'/Users/lukeschoenberger/Documents/Programming/news-
arg/test6/ios/build/test6/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/test6.app/AntDesign.ttf'

** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: I think this error is coming because you are importing FontAwesome5Pro Icon in your file. Just use FontAwsome5 icon and you will not get this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Icon module does not appear to be properly linked.

You can try `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

If this is not a workaround,

Delete all items in the build folder under the iOS folder. Then rebuild the project with `react-native run-ios`.

Comment: I'm receiving another error now about a differect react-native-vector-icon font. made an edit to the original post with what it is. This is after I cleared the build folder and linked

Comment: Try this as well. Xcode->File->Project Settings-> Build System -> Legacy Build System.

Answer (score 0):

Regular, Solid, and Brand Icons TTF File import android and ios directory

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-fontawesome/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added `<string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>` to `Info.plist` [under "Fonts provided by application"](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons?tab=readme-ov-file#ios-setup)